# Modifying invisible API method codes

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, invisible

I am using invisible API library in asp.net, and I should call all API endpoints inside this invisible API configuration, in documentation written  like this:

```
app.UseInvisibleApis(new List<InvisibleApiConfiguration>
        {
            new InvisibleApiConfiguration
            {
                Endpoint = "/api/home",
                Header = "Hush",
                Value = "I'm a good guy",
                HttpVerb = "GET"
            }
        });
```

This just for one API endpoint, how can I add multiple endpoints, if I write all of them like this, codes becoming huge. And also can I also add multiple http methods?

I write this method:

```
private static InvisibleApiConfiguration CreateInvisibleApiConfiguration(
        string endpoint, string httpVerb, string header, string value)
    {
        return new InvisibleApiConfiguration
        {
            Endpoint = endpoint,
            HttpVerb = httpVerb,
            Header = header,
            Value = value
        };
    }
```

and call this inside configuration to make code lines smaller, but not help:

```
CreateInvisibleApiConfiguration("/api/Scores", "POST",
            "SecretHeaderScores", "SecretValueScores"),
        CreateInvisibleApiConfiguration("/api/Scores", "GET",
            "SecretHeaderScores", "SecretValueScores"),
        CreateInvisibleApiConfiguration("/api/Scores", "PUT",
            "SecretHeaderScores", "SecretValueScores"),
        CreateInvisibleApiConfiguration("/api/Scores", "DELETE",
            "SecretHeaderScores", "SecretValueScores"),
```

like this lines become huge.

Comment: How about shortening the function's name to `InvisApiConfig` and making the duplicated parameter values the default values of the `header` & `value` parameters?

Comment: I'm sceptical about the whole idea of the [library](https://github.com/hassanhabib/InvisibleApi) you are using there. Restricting access to certain endpoints could be done in a much safer way using role based access (i.e. the user token must contain certain claims to use restricted endpoints).

Comment: Hi, thanks for comment, this is my task and i can not use another method to make api invisible.